# Android image animation

Tags: android

I've been doing the following for the last three days without any success.

Suppose I have one image. I have set that image invisible in my XML layout. Now I want to make it visible through animation. Suppose translate animation.

Suppose there is point A and point B. On point B I have already set the image invisible. From point A I want a translate animation effect. And when it completes, the image B becomes visible.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using ViewFlipper (or ViewAnimator) setting your ImageView as children and defining animation effect for transition

Comment: hi..Thanks for replying.
do u have any sample code for the same?